# How to escape "$@" in a makefile?

Tags: bash, make, escape-characters, makefile, escaping

```
test:
    @echo "#!/bin/bash\njava -classpath \"$(CLASSPATH)\" com.atm.ATM \"$@\"" > test
    @chmod a+x test
```

I am trying to escape the "$@" so that it literally appears in the "test" script as "$@" (passing the arguments invoked on the bash script to the java program).

Things that I have tried:

```
"$$@" -> ""
"$$@@" -> "@"
"$@@" -> "<target>@"
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 11):

Figured out how to escape it - needed a backslash: `"\$$@"`